# Gnuplot memory usage trace

Tags: memory-management, plot, gnuplot

Before I dive deep in gnuplot I have some questions regarding its usage.
The data file contains several lines in the following pattern, separated by white space

> ```
> S Allocation_time Free_Time
>
> 40 1259244359200 1259244360041
>  6 1259244363756 1259244367637 
>  6 1259244368304 1259244368555
>  6 1259244368494 1259244369337
>  6 1259244359583 1259244369517
> 308 1259244361496 1259244369713
> 12 1259244361291 1259244369875
> 28 1259244362636 1259244370017
> ```

The first column is the allocated size, the second one is the allocation time and the last is the free time.

What I want to achieve is a histogram over time, showing the total memory usage, based on the allocation and de allocation time.

So as long as the current's lines free time is smaller than the allocation time of the next line's, plot the allocation and deallocation accordingly.

However, sometimes the free_time can be larger than the next allocation (the allocation is not supposed to get freed yet), so I want to store those occasions in a structure, and when eventually there is something to free, search through this structure and compare the allocation and free time.

Is this even possible in gnuplot, or should I look in another plotting mechanism? This trace file is input to a program I wrote, and I would like to verify that the output is similar to the original tracing.

Thank you everyone in advance.

Comment: That sounds to me like something that should be done in python or some other scripting language that lets you build up lists and other data structures. Gnuplot can't really do what you describe, and it would take a lot of effort. You could certainly convert the data into something gnuplot could plot.

Comment: I thought so. Thank you for your suggestion